# tensorflow _curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal

Tags: python, tensorflow, curses

When I use `TFDBG` to debug my program on ubuntu, I got this error:

> _curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal.

I have tried to set enviroment variables `TERM` and `TERMINFO`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'd use `strace` to trace system calls to see which terminfo directory it actually tried using.

Comment: I run my program in command line，instead of in Pycharm，then it works

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question :-)  You might discover that the python script successfully read a terminal entry, but that the environment in which you are running is not actually a terminal.  The system calls and results would show that clearly.